Trying to solve an exercise on double integration
I have a problem with the following integral:
$$
\iint_{\Omega}y^{2}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y,
$$
$$
\mbox{where}\quad 
\Omega \equiv 
\left\{\left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}\ \mid\
x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 2\quad\mbox{and}\quad
0 \leq x^{3} \leq y\right\}
$$
MY ATTEMPT
Making a picture of our domain, I see that it is given by the portion of the plane contained between the circle of radius $2$, the $y$-axis and the curve $y = x^{3}$. Thus $y$ may vary between $0$ and $2$, while $x$ varies from $0$ to $\displaystyle\sqrt[3\,]{\,{y}\,}$.
So doing I get
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2}y^{2}\,\sqrt[3]{y}\,{\rm d}y$, easy to be solved. Is my argument correct ?.

No, because you not considered the circle. You just assumed it is a straight line.

Ok, can you give a complete solution?

Did you make that picture? You can see that the limits of $x$ change depending on $y$.

The plot of the domain $\Omega$ is the intersection of the red and blue region in the following image:

We will describe this domain with vertical slices. As you can see, $0 \le x \le 1$. For each $x \in [0, 1]$, $y$ goes from $x^3$ to $\sqrt{2 - x^2}$. Therefore,
$$
     \iint_{\Omega} y^2 dA = \int_0^1 \int_{x^3}^{\sqrt{2 - x^2}} y^2 dy dx = \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{3}[(2 - x^2)\sqrt{2 - x^2} - x^9]dx = \dfrac{3}{10} + \dfrac{\pi}{8}
$$
If you want to describe the domain with horizontal slices, notice that, for each $y \in [0, 1]$, $x$ goes from  $0$ to $y^{1/3}$, and for each $y \in [1, \sqrt{2}]$, $x$ goes from $0$ to $\sqrt{2 - y^2}$. Therefore,
$$
    \iint_{\Omega} y^2 dA = \int_0^1 \int_0^{y^{1/3}} y^2 dx dy + \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{2 - y^2}} y^2 dx dy = \int_0^1 y^{7/3}dy + \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} y^2 \sqrt{2 - y^2}dy
$$

Thank you very much! Well, at same point you will work with the integral $\int_0^1 (2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx$. Which substitution do you use to solve it?

@TheWanderer Factor out 2 to get $$ 2 \sqrt{2} \left(1 - \dfrac{x^2}{2} \right)^{3/2}$$ Now, do trig substitution $x = \sqrt{2} \sin \phi$
